# Getting response status code: 404, headers when trying to upload a very large JSON string to server using NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to upload a very large JSON string to server using `NSMutableURLRequest`. If the length of `postData` is `239741` then it is giving the following response :

```
 { status code: 404, headers {
 Connection = "keep-alive";
 "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
 "Content-Type" = "text/html";
 Date = "Fri, 04 Dec 2015 09:12:30 GMT";
 Server = "nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)";
 "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
 } }
```

But if I try to post JSON string to server with `postData` length of 206044, then data gets successfully uploaded to server.

How can I upload a JSON string of unlimited length to a server?

Complete code given below :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“URL Here”];
NSData *postData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@",postValues] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token %@",AuthToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:50];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSError *error1 = nil;

NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;
NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error1];
NSLog(@"response is %@",response);
NSString* responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"response string is %@",responseString);
if (responseData) {
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error1];
    return json;
}
else
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error1.description);
```

Comment: Have you check your `URL` is it works or not?

Comment: Yes, URL is working fine. This error is currently dependent on [postData Length] i.e upto a limit request is working fine and if go beyond that I'm getting this response

Comment: Are you sure you're not changing the URL when you are posting this longer JSON? Please post your code.

Comment: @PeterH can you please know me what size of data are you sending on `WS`.

Comment: @NimitParekh if you mean by the file size of data, then it's 400 KB in size

Comment: @PeterH I hope then it's not an issue for the size probably..

Comment: @jcaron I'm not changing the URL, the complete code has been provided above.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same request using another tool, e.g. command-line curl? Do you have access to the server's logs? If so, can you check the access log for the actual URL requested, and the error log for any error? The fact that you use stringWithFormat for your URL makes me believe that in your actual code you do have variable parts in the URL. Log the URL (or the request) just before sending it just to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check your web-service `URL`.

> The 404 or Not Found error message is an HTTP standard response code
>   indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given
>   server, but the server could not find what was requested.

You can check your web-service using different plugin available on `Google Chrome` and `Mozila firefox` which is listed below.

1. [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-launcher/igofndmniooofoabmmpfonmdnhgchoka?hl=en)
2. [REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

May this helps lot.

Answer (score 1):

Look up what status 404 means. Google is your friend here. It means the url that you are using doesn't exist on the server. At least that's what the server says.

Comment: This fixed my error. I was calling an URL that doesn't exist on the web server.